Using Bun in Azure pipelines
I followed the guide here:https://johnnyreilly.com/using-bun-in-azure-pipelines and it works.
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: setup bun
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'install -g bun'
    verbose: true

However, it'll be installing bun on every build if I'm not wrong?
For context:
/usr/local/bin/npm install -g bun

added 3 packages in 21s
npm verbose cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
npm info using npm@10.7.0
npm info using node@v18.20.3
npm verbose title npm install bun
npm verbose argv "install" "--global" "bun"
npm verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2024-07-02T11_06_44_941Z-
npm verbose logfile /home/vsts/.npm/_logs/2024-07-02T11_06_44_941Z-debug-0.log
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bun 1126ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven%2fbun-linux-x64 1600ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven%2fbun-darwin-x64 1539ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven%2fbun-windows-x64 1608ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven%2fbun-linux-aarch64 1580ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven%2fbun-darwin-aarch64 1602ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven%2fbun-linux-x64-baseline 1567ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven%2fbun-darwin-x64-baseline 1586ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven%2fbun-windows-x64-baseline 1587ms (cache miss)
npm verbose reify failed optional dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bun/node_modules/@oven/bun-windows-x64-baseline
npm verbose reify failed optional dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bun/node_modules/@oven/bun-windows-x64
npm verbose reify failed optional dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bun/node_modules/@oven/bun-linux-aarch64
npm verbose reify failed optional dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bun/node_modules/@oven/bun-darwin-x64-baseline
npm verbose reify failed optional dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bun/node_modules/@oven/bun-darwin-x64
npm verbose reify failed optional dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bun/node_modules/@oven/bun-darwin-aarch64
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bun/-/bun-1.1.17.tgz 728ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven/bun-linux-x64/-/bun-linux-x64-1.1.17.tgz 3743ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@oven/bun-linux-x64-baseline/-/bun-linux-x64-baseline-1.1.17.tgz 3790ms (cache miss)
npm info run bun@1.1.17 postinstall node_modules/bun node install.js
npm info run bun@1.1.17 postinstall { code: 0, signal: null }
npm verbose exit 0
npm info ok
Finishing: setup bun

Is there anyway to cache or make it install only once?

I noticed in the log that it added 3 packages in 21s. In fact, it takes very little time, and the advantage of downloading it every time is that if the package is updated, the latest package will be downloaded.


However, it'll be installing bun on every build if I'm not wrong?

Yes

Is there anyway to cache or make it install only once?

Pipeline caching might help in this case, as it can help reduce build time by allowing the outputs or downloaded dependencies from one run to be reused in later runs. See enable caching in a Node.js project.
As an alternative, and if you're using self-hosted build agents, consider installing bun in the build agent itself.

Agreed with Rui's answer and the following is a sample yaml to use Pipeline caching to cache the bun packages.
When installing use -g option, it will be installed to  /usr/local/lib/node_modules (Use npm root -g to check where.) So, I use the tree command to check if the package is correctly installed to that path.
When the cache is not found, the Npm install task will run and install the bun packages. When the cache is found and restored, the Npm install task will be skipped.
trigger: 
  - none
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'bun | "$(Agent.OS)" '
    restoreKeys: |
      bun | "$(Agent.OS)"
    path: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bun
    cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED
  displayName: Cache bun packages

- bash: tree /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bun

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: install bun when no cache is found
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'install -g bun '
    verbose: true
  condition: eq(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'false')

- bash: tree /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bun


